# Use leaflet.js inside SVG tag

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

Is it possible to draw the map inside the SVG tag? Which probably means there'd have to be SVG only version of the map without divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`foreignObject` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) to embed HTML into SVG, and that works quite well with Leaflet:

```html
<svg>
    <foreignobject x="46" y="22" width="200" height="200">
        <div id='map'></div>
    </foreignobject>
</svg>
```

```
// setup your map as usual
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 12);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
```

And a demo

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 12);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin=""></script>
   


<svg>
    <foreignobject x="46" y="22" width="200" height="200">
        <div id='map'></div>
    </foreignobject>
</svg>
```